# How to use switch statement with 'onCheckedChanged' method in android?

Tags: java, android, switch-statement, oncheckedchanged

I have been trying for ages to get this to work and I want it so that I can put both checkedChanged in one OnCheckedChanged method. What I have so far doesn't work, but as I had it before with only one case, without the switch statement worked. Please can you look at my code and see how I can fix it to make it work?

Here is the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnCheckedChangeListener {

    Button sensorButton;
    Button newScreen;
    Switch vibrateToggle;
    Switch lightsToggle;
    NotificationManager nm1;
    NotificationManager nm2;
    static final int uniqueID1 = 12345;
    static final int uniqueID2 = 54321;
    OnCheckedChangeListener vibrateListener;
    OnCheckedChangeListener lightsListener;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        sensorButton = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.sensorButton);
        sensorButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        newScreen = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.newScreen);
        newScreen.setOnClickListener(this);

        nm1 = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        nm1.cancel(uniqueID1);

        nm2 = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        nm2.cancel(uniqueID2); 

        vibrateToggle = (Switch)this.findViewById(R.id.switch1);
        vibrateToggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(vibrateListener);

        lightsToggle = (Switch)this.findViewById(R.id.lightSwitch);
        lightsToggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(lightsListener);    
    }


    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(buttonView.getId()){

        case R.id.switch1:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Vibrate Notification is " + (isChecked ? "ON" : "OFF"),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (isChecked) {
                    // The toggle is enabled
                    Intent vibrateIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                    PendingIntent vibratePi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, vibrateIntent, 0);
                    NotificationCompat.Builder vibrateN = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
                    vibrateN.setContentIntent(vibratePi);
                    vibrateN.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE);
                    Notification vn = vibrateN.build();
                    nm2.notify(uniqueID2, vn);
                } else {
                    // The toggle is disabled
                }

        case R.id.lightSwitch:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Lights Notification is " + (isChecked ? "ON" : "OFF"),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    if (isChecked) {
                        // The toggle is enabled
                        Intent lightsIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
                        PendingIntent lightsPi = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, lightsIntent, 0);
                        NotificationCompat.Builder lightsN = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
                        lightsN.setContentIntent(lightsPi);
                        lightsN.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS);
                        Notification ln = lightsN.build();
                        nm2.notify(uniqueID2, ln);
                    } else {
                        // The toggle is disabled
                    }

             break;
        }
    }
```

This is the logcat that I get:

```
03-14 16:46:21.139: D/dalvikvm(532): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
03-14 16:46:22.218: I/dalvikvm(532): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
03-14 16:46:22.338: I/dalvikvm(532): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
03-14 16:46:22.728: I/dalvikvm(532): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
03-14 16:46:22.739: I/dalvikvm(532): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
03-14 16:46:23.238: I/dalvikvm(532): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
03-14 16:46:23.278: I/dalvikvm(532): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
03-14 16:46:23.509: D/gralloc_goldfish(532): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
03-14 16:46:25.258: D/AndroidRuntime(532): Shutting down VM
03-14 16:46:25.258: W/dalvikvm(532): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
03-14 16:46:25.288: E/AndroidRuntime(532): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-14 16:46:25.288: E/AndroidRuntime(532): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method onSwitchToggle(View) in the activity class com.example.sensor.MainActivity for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Switch with id 'switch1'
03-14 16:46:25.288: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3031)
03-14 16:46:25.288: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
03-14 16:46:25.288: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:100)
03-14 16:46:25.288: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
03-14 16:46:25.288: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
03-14 16:46:25.288: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-14 16:46:25.288: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-14 16:46:25.288: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
03-14 16:46:25.288: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-14 16:46:25.288: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-14 16:46:25.288: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-14 16:46:25.288: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-14 16:46:25.288: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-14 16:46:25.288: E/AndroidRuntime(532): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: onSwitchToggle [class android.view.View]
03-14 16:46:25.288: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
03-14 16:46:25.288: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:915)
03-14 16:46:25.288: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3024)
03-14 16:46:25.288: E/AndroidRuntime(532):  ... 12 more
03-14 16:46:25.948: I/dalvikvm(532): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
03-14 16:46:25.958: I/dalvikvm(532): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
```

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK : you don't _must_, (otherwise it would be useless) but you really should, in most case

Comment: solved or not still getting issue?

Comment: I added the break, but it didn't fix the problem. The application still crashes when I click on either one of the Switch buttons. Is there any other way of fixing this problem?

Comment: @JamesMeade : plz add logcat result with question

Comment: I have just added the logcat to the original post

Comment: @JamesMeade: @JamesMeade : in xml of `switch1` Switch View  you have added `android:onClick="onSwitchToggle"`  attribute ? then just remove it

Answer (score 4):

As in log:

> NoSuchMethodException: onSwitchToggle [class android.view.View]

means you have added an `android:onClick="onSwitchToggle"` attribute in `Switch` View xml but you forgot to define the method in your `Activity` code.

Because you are adding `setOnCheckedChangeListener()` to `Switch` View in `Activity`, then there's no need to set `onClick()` inside the XML for the `Switch` View. Just remove the `android:onClick="onSwitchToggle"` attribute from XML.